# Spring MVC Controller Return JSON - Error 406

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc, spring-roo

After searching all the related links in StackOverflow for the given title I am posting this question.

My Controller code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/update", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody List<Users> getContentSummaryData(@RequestParam String user, @RequestParam String userid){
        return Users.findAllUsers();
    }
```

And My jquery request is as follows:

```
$.getJSON("user/update", { user: "user", userid:"1230" }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

But as usual a 406 error in console which is as follows:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/mycontext/user/update?user=user&userid=1230 406 (Not Acceptable)
```

According to every configuration found in here(StackOverflow), I checked and rechecked.
I have been fighting with problem since past 1 hour. Can anybody help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting this I researched again. 
I found that two JARs required. I added them to classpath.

[jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.4.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.4/jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.jar) & [jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.4/jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.jar)

Its now working fine. Phewwww....