# Spring MVC always return 406 (already searched from other forums)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am a new for Spring, using Spring 4.2.0. I want to return a JSON to client. It always return 406 error to client.

Here is my code,

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/account",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    headers="Accept=*/*"
)
@ResponseBody
public Object account() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    JSONArray result = null;
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(baseURL+"/user/accountuser/2");
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authenCode);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    String json = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
    try {
        result = new JSONArray(json); // here is a json array from 3rd services
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried solution from this question [Spring MVC Controller Return JSON - Error 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345505/spring-mvc-controller-return-json-error-406) by using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

It's still same.

After that I tried this solution [spring mvc not returning json content - error 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069903/spring-mvc-not-returning-json-content-error-406) by using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

instead of before solution, but it's still same.

Moreover, I changed a lot of thing in the @RequestMapping such as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/account",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
@RequestMapping(value = "/account",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

it's still same too.

I've faced on this problem for 2 day. I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you set log level `DEBUG` on package `org.springframework.web` and post the output?

Comment: @ksokol 
I don't know the right way to set log level to DEBUG, but this output shown in the console,
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: Ok. Two more questions:-) What logging framework do you use? Do you use Spring in a servlet container like Tomcat or do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: @ksokol I'm using Tomcat.

Comment: Ok. It will take some hours to provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is based on Spring's [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). It is a convenient approach to talk to remote services. Various [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) transform request/response objects into common formats like XML or JSON out of the box as long as the necessary library is available on classpath.

Your code even doesn't require `Jackson` because it acts as a proxy for a third party service. Please keep in mind. This is a demo and not meant to be used in a production system as is.

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void account(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<Resource> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl + "/user/accountuser/2", HttpMethod.GET, createEntity(), Resource.class);
        IOUtils.copy(exchange.getBody().getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
    }

    private HttpEntity<String> createEntity() {
        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(AUTHORIZATION, "someCode");
        httpHeaders.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new HttpEntity<String>(httpHeaders);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two things that are causing this exception, the missing dependencies, or a return value that is not a proper java bean. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825276/spring-4-restcontroller-json-characteristics-not-acceptable-according-to-the-re/26826136#26826136)

If you remove the `codehaus` dependencies and leave only `fasterxml` you can be certain that you have proper `jackson` dependencies to feed the converter.

Your problem is however that `JSONArray` is not a proper java bean. To get it working you can simplify your method to

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/account",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
@ResponseBody
public String account() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(baseURL+"/user/accountuser/2");
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authenCode);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    String json = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
    return json;
}
```

and register `application/json` type, either in xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
<mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
    <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
               <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                   <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                   <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                   <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven >
```

or in java config

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_HTML, 
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    converters.add(stringConverter);
}
```

The fact that you're posting a new get request inside a controller looks very suspicious, but I won't go into that.

What happens when you apply this solution is that, you say that your method will produce a response with `json` content-type. And since the method is returning `String`, your adding a config so that `StringHttpMessageConverter` can apply for `json` type as well